# Installing kubuntu-desktop on 15.10 Fails and Breaks APT

Tags: apt, package-management, kubuntu, dependencies, 15.10

I'm not using a PPA for KDE, just the stock version. I tried installing kubuntu-desktop and it failed with the following:

```
Unpacking kde-config-telepathy-accounts (4:15.08.2-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.08.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service', which is also in package account-plugin-google 0.12+15.10.20150723-0ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.08.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) code here
```

I can no longer update, install, or remove any packages. All operations result in an error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
kde-telepathy-minimal : Depends: kde-config-telepathy-accounts (>= 15.04.0) but it is not going to be installed
unity-scope-gdrive : Depends: account-plugin-google but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Running "apt-get -f install" just results in the original error above.

I saw a suggestion to use synaptic to force remove the account-plugin-google package but I don't have synaptic installed and obviously can't install it now as far as I can tell. This is the result of "apt-get install synaptic":

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
kde-telepathy-minimal : Depends: kde-config-telepathy-accounts (>= 15.04.0) but it is not going to be installed
synaptic : Depends: libept1.4.16 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libvte-2.90-9 (>= 1:0.27.2) but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: libgtk2-perl (>= 1:1.130) but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: rarian-compat but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 5):

After some reading up on APT I was able to finish the kubuntu-desktop install (apt-get install -f) and get APT generally working again. I had to force-remove account-plugin-google and its dependency unity-scope-drive:

```
dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq account-plugin-google unity-scope-gdrive
```

I have not attempted to reinstall those packages so I don't know if this is a real "fix" but it at least got APT working again.